# How to detecte no results in GMSAutocompleteViewController

Tags: objective-c, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using `GMSAutocompleteViewController` to get places in my app which make it easier to the user and neat to my server data. and this is my code below.
My question is how can I detect of the auto-complete returned no result so I can handle this ?

```
#pragma mark - GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate
// Handle the user's selection.
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // Do something with the selected place.
    [_institutionTextField setText:place.name];
    [_addressTextField setText:[[place.addressComponents objectAtIndex:0] name]];

    [errorStatus replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [errorStatus replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    [experinceDictionary setObject:@{@"name":place.name,
                                     @"latitude":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:place.coordinate.latitude],
                                     @"longitude":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:place.coordinate.longitude],
                                     @"address":place.formattedAddress,
                                     @"google_place_id":place.placeID}
                            forKey:@"hospital"];
}

- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController didFailAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // TODO: handle the error.
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}

// User canceled the operation.
- (void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
- (void)didRequestAutocompletePredictions:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}

- (void)didUpdateAutocompletePredictions:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == _institutionTextField) {
        GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];

        acController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know when the user closes the GMSAutocompleteViewController without selecting a place, or do you want to know when no predictions are returned for something they have typed.?

Comment: I want to know when no predictions are returned for something they have typed

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately there's no way to know that at the moment. I'm curious, though. What action do you want to take when there are no predictions returned?

Comment: @AndrewR to make the user enter the place name or take his search text as a place name!